# HttpRequest.Base64 not found in FireBaseCrashlytic new version

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I migrated FireBase fabric to FireBase Crashlytic but When I migrate FireBaseCrashlytic HttpRequest.Base64 not found in new version and it gives error "Base64 not found", how to change HttpRequest.Base64 for new version

old Version FireBase

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest;

    public static String encrypt(String src) {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), makeIv());
                return HttpRequest.Base64.encodeBytes(cipher.doFinal(src.getBytes()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

new version Firebase

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest;

    public static String encrypt(String src) {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), makeIv());
                return HttpRequest.Base64.encodeBytes(cipher.doFinal(src.getBytes()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```